# What options exist on Mac OS X for software that makes architectural diagrams?

Tags: macos, diagram

I am an OS X user.  Often, I need to share architectural, workflow and other data with managers and developers in a visual fashion.

Can anyone recommend me some software and tell me why it's awesome?

Comment: Feel free to move this to a better Stack Exchange location (Apple forum?).  For what it's worth, I got a great answer to my question, and am very happy using the solution recommended by MissT.  The other upvotes on the answer also encouraged me to pursue that solution.  Thank you Stack Overflow community!

Comment: Some more options can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6490/12227

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I love OmniGraffle for diagrams
http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/
Easy to use, the result really look great, and support various programmer stuff like UML.
A lot better than visio

Comment: Marcus, just make sure to look for extra templates ("stencils") online. The one thing Omnigraffle is weak on compared to visio is in the built-it set and in it's support for browsing community stuff.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because after evaluating OmniGraffle, I think I am going to use it.  I have not evaluated anything else, so, all I'm saying is that OmniGraffle will meet my needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am a big fan of [ConceptDraw Pro](http://www.conceptdraw.com/en/products/cd5/main.php)